# Lerp between two values over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, floating-point

I'm trying to reduce a float by a time value, i'm using Unity and stopping time `Time.timeScale = 0f;` so can not use `Time.deltaTime` so using 'Time.realtimeSinceStartup' in a while loop, i read in the master volume variable from a global script that the player can set in game between 0 - 1 so say i read in 0.6 and i want to lower the volume to 0 in 2 second how do i get the percentage to keep reducing the volume by ?

Here is my code ..

```
 private IEnumerator VolumeDown ()
{
    float volumeIncrease = globalVarsScript.musicVolume;
    float volumePercentage = ??;
    float newLerpEndTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + 2f;

    while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < newLerpEndTime)
    {
        audio.volume = volumeIncrease;
        volumeIncrease -= volumePercentage;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Sorry i just can't get the 'volumePercentage'

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a _tick_ of - let's say - 100 ms then roughly `(current - final) / (time / tick)` and you have the step to add for each step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm using Unity and stopping time `Time.timeScale = 0f;` so can not use
>   `Time.deltaTime` so using 'Time.realtimeSinceStartup' in a while loop.

You don't need to use `Time.realtimeSinceStartup` for this. It is true that setting `Time.timeScale` to *0* makes  [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to return *0* every frame.

This is why [`Time.unscaledDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html) was added in *Unity 4.5* to address that. Simply replace the `Time.deltaTime` with `Time.unscaledDeltaTime`. You can event use `if (Time.timeScale == 0)` to automatically decide whether to use `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` or `Time.deltaTime`.

```
IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0f;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            counter += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        else
            counter += Time.deltaTime;

        float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);
        Debug.Log("Val: " + val);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(5, 1, 3));
```

The value changes from `5` to `1` within `3` seconds. It doesn't matter if `Time.timeScale` is set to `1` or `0`.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know about 'Time.unscaledDeltaTime' thats one to add to my information database .. Thank you.